# angularjs ng-focus and controller %% directives in one .js file

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am trying to implement a little function, but facing a little problem here:

1. Looking at my .js file, is it the right way to include controller and directive at the same time in one script file?
2. how am I supposed to implement further based on my code to make a workable module here like the link below(css doesn't need to be look fancy, if it expands that's fine):

   http://plnkr.co/edit/bWUmjHdnXidfGuaRfqo5?p=preview

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

var MasterCtrl = function (user, $state) {
       
       var self =this;

       self.app = {
           state: {
               onFocusSearch: false
           }
       };
       self.enterSearch = function() {
           self.app.state.onFocusSearch = true;
       };

       self.leaveSearch = function() {
           self.app.state.onFocusSearch = false;
       };
   };
    angular.module('master', []);

    angular.module('master').directive('lsMasterHeader', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'modules/master/directive/header.html',
            link: function() {}
        };
    })
    .controller('MasterCtrl', MasterCtrl);
})();
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-horizontal" placeholder="Enter a Message" ng-class="{'yourAnimateCssRule': master.app.state.onFocusSearch}" ng-focus="master.enterSearch()" ng-focus="master.leaveSearch()" />
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </button>   
  </div>
</form>
```

thanks.

Comment: You're not defining any controller. You're defining a local function, and never using it anywhere. Registering a controller consists, like for a directive, in calling `angular.module('master').controller("TheControllerName", theControllerFunction);`. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Seems like codepen is angular less..

Comment: @JBNizet how about defining a module above the directive first and adding a controller at the bottom like that?

Comment: @PankajParkar changed the link

Comment: Ah, now you're registering the controller function after the directive. That's correct, but bad practice. It's easier to maintain when you have one component per file.

Comment: @kkagill you could place directive and controller in the different file, and they can be bound to same or different module..likewise you can have multiple files which will have different component to it..